# How to convert double to string without the power to 10 representation (E-05)

Tags: c#, tostring

How to convert double to string without the power to 10 representation (E-05)

```
double value = 0.000099999999833333343;
string text = value.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(text); // 9,99999998333333E-05
```

I'd like the string *text* to be 0.000099999999833333343 (or nearly that, I'm not doing rocket science:)

I've tried the following variants

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());      // 9,99999998333333E-05
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("R20")); // 9,9999999833333343E-05
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N20")); // 0,00009999999983333330
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F20}", value)); // 0,00009999999983333330
```

Doing tostring N20 or format F20 seems closest to what I want, but I do end up with a lot of trailing zeros, is there a clever way to avoid this? I'd like to get as close to the double representation as possible 0.000099999999833333343

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) with the [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687(VS.71).aspx).  I think you want {0:F20} or so.

```
string formatted = String.Format("{0:F20}", value);
```

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
Convert.ToDecimal(doubleValue).ToString()
```

Comment: This is a clever idea, but the range of `float` (`e 3.402823e38`) is greater than the range of `decimal` (`79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335`).  Thus large value will cause an exception.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `string.Format()`.  Just put the right [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) in the existing `.ToString()` method.  Something like "N" should do.

Comment: string.Format with 'N' will add commas, it will not just use integers to form the string. Example: 34634859436785434 will show up as "34,634,859,436,785,400.00"

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Format` with an appropriate format specifier.

This blog post has a lot of examples: http://blogs.msdn.com/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx

Comment: When down voting, please leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Link is now broken. I think this is the correct link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kathykam/net-format-string-101