# Convert double value with E-02 to "normal" value

Tags: vb6

I have the double value

```
3,64171229302883E-02
```

I would like to convert it so that the E-02 is gone and zeros are used instead.

How would I do that in VB6, please?

Comment: [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603013/easier-way-to-prevent-numbers-from-showing-in-exponent-notation) You should see your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming its in a string cast to Decimal ("," is locale specific, for me its ".")

```
?cdec("3.64171229302883E-02")
 0.0364171229302883
```

Comment: This answer is actually wrong; it just appears to do what expected because the default rules for converting doubles and decimals to strings differ. The right way is `Format$(3.64171229302883E-02#, "0.##################")` or `FormatNumber(3.64171229302883E-02#, 16)`.