# C# Double to String without exponential

Tags: c#, string, format, double, exponential

I get a double value after certain calculation as **1084218256710914.2**

When I convert it to string, it gives me value in some format which contains E i.e exponential part.

I tried `string.Format("{0:F8}", value);`

which gave me "**1,084,218,256,710,910.00000000**" as I want max 8 digits after decimal points.

I want output like this "**1084218256710914.2**"

Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert double to string without the power to 10 representation (E-05)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319191/how-to-convert-double-to-string-without-the-power-to-10-representation-e-05)

Comment: I have tried that but the problem is it resets everything after decimal point as you can see the values I've given. It ends with 914.2 but after conversion it's 910.0. I want the values after decimal points as well

Comment: use "R" as format string. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611552/c-sharp-converting-20-digit-precision-double-to-string-and-back-again

Comment: Even R worked like G17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value.ToString("G17");` should do the trick.